# Save remaining seconds in countdown timer

Tags: c#, countdowntimer

I have a problem. I want to save the remaining seconds in countdown timer (for example, the remaining time = 12 seconds) i want to save that 12 seconds in a variable.
this is my code

```
    int order = 0;
    bool right = true;
    DispatcherTimer timer1 = new DispatcherTimer();
    private void timer_start()
    {
        timer1.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Start();

    }
    int remainingSecond;
    int tik = 15;
    void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Timer.Text = tik.ToString();
        if (tik > 0)
        {
            tik--;
            if (this.order >= 5)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                if (right)
                {
                    remainingSecond = tik;
                }
                else
                    remainingSecond = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            remainingSecond = 0;
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
```

everytime I write "remainingSecond" , its value is always 0. I wish that `remainingSecond` value is 12. Help me, please. Thanks

Comment: Rather than `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1)` (which creates a 1-millisecond timer), write `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)`.

Comment: i think `remainingSecond = tik` is wrong, but i don't know how to correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assigned `order = 0` but did not increase it any where and set this condition

`if (this.order >= 5)` which will never true. So it will keep decrementing your `tik` and at the end your this condition `if (tik > 0)` will become false. So else will be executed and it will set your `remainingSecond` to `ZERO`. Thats why you are getting ZERO as output.

Your timer is ticking in every 1milisecond. The `timer` will start, and it will `tick` immediately, at that time `order` will be **zero**, and your else statement will get executed that will set `remainingSeconds` to **ZERo** and will `Stop` the timer as well. So the clicking on the buttons won't do anything for you.

Comment: There's a procedure if buttons (there are 5 different buttons, for example 1,2,3,4,5) is clicked, `order++`, also `right` can be `false` if we clicked in wrong order (for ex. 2,3,1,4,5)

Comment: this is it (just one procedure, the others are same) `private void number1_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            this.order++;
            if (this.order != 1) this.right = false;
        }`

Comment: so what should I do so that the `remainingSecond` can save the value of `tik` ? I'm really stuck in this. Thanks before

Comment: Yes ! because the timer would have stoped before your clicking. I try to sort out problem. How much time are you giving user to click on all the buttons?

Comment: My plan is after 5 clicks, the timer stops and there will be remaining seconds, I want to save that remaining seconds into `remainingSecond`.

Comment: So your total time is 12 sec. You are giving 12 sec to user to click on all the buttons in sequence. and after completion you want to find out the remaining time. Am i right on everything?

Comment: the total time is 15 seconds, the remaining seconds can be 12, 10, or others. Yup you guess it right :D

Comment: Use this : `timer1.Interval = 1000`

Comment: it can't convert `int` into `System.TimeSpan` , right? I tried using `timer1.interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)` , the `remainingSecond` is still 0

Comment: OK ! so use this : `timer1.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000)`

Comment: or may be this is usefull for you `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000).TotalMilliseconds`

Comment: If it helped you !! choose it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the interval for 1 second instead of 1 millisecond

Comment: the value of `remainingSecond` is still the same :(